# a-weighting as digital filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, digital-filter

I'm trying to create a digital filter that creates close results to the a-weighting specification: [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting)

I have already created simple low- and high-pass with 2<sup>nd</sup> and 6<sup>th</sup> order IIR filters. I also created a cascaded second order sequence of 3 biquads. These filters seem to work quite well. I'm generating the coefficients with the octave/matlab `butter` and `tf2sos` functions. The filter is implemented in C++ and applied to my audio input. The processed audio gets converted to the frequency domain and is displayed on my screen.

Now is my question how I can implement the a-weighting filter. I already tried the matlab code I found on the internet:

```
Fs = 44100;
f1 = 20.598997; 
f2 = 107.65265;
f3 = 737.86223;
f4 = 12194.217;
A1000 = 1.9997;
pi = 3.14159265358979;
NUMs = [ (2*pi*f4)^2*(10^(A1000/20)) 0 0 0 0 ];
DENs = conv([1 +4*pi*f4 (2*pi*f4)^2],[1 +4*pi*f1 (2*pi*f1)^2]); 
DENs = conv(conv(DENs,[1 2*pi*f3]),[1 2*pi*f2]);
[B,A] = bilinear(NUMs,DENs,Fs);

printf('%0.16f\n',A);
1.0000000000000000
5.9999984423677502
14.9999922118394622
19.9999844236803490
14.9999844236817736
5.9999922118415991
0.9999984423684625

printf('%0.16f\n',B);
0.0000000000000000
-0.0000000000000000
-0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000
-0.0000000000000000
-0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000
```

These coefficients look strange, and they also do not work with my 6<sup>th</sup> order IIR. So I tried to create cascaded biquads:

```
sos = tf2sos(B,A);
printf('%0.16f\n',sos);
0.0000000000000000
1.0000000000000000
1.0000000000000000
-0.0000000000000000
-2.0001419687327253
1.9999999999999987
0.0000000000000000
1.0001419788113322
0.9999999999999984
1.0000000000000000
1.0000000000000000
1.0000000000000000
2.0044328398652649
1.9955456521230652
2.0000199503794249
1.0044526299594496
0.9955653535664766
1.0000002046824734
```

but these coefficients do not work either. Could it be because the coefficients are wrong in the first place?

Can someone point me out, how to implement a digital a-weighting filter correctly?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to SleuthEye's answer below, I could implement the a-weighting filter with the correct coefficients from octave.

I found a lot of different filter c++ implementations on the web and in win32-filter-generator applications, but they seemed all inconsistent.

Finally I found two code-snippets that essentially work in the same way:

- https://github.com/berndporr/iir1/blob/master/iir/State.h 
  (has also a youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/DSPcourse)
- http://www.earlevel.com/main/2012/11/26/biquad-c-source-code/ (a and b are swapped here)

So I basically copied the code from there and ended up with this: (its the transposed direct form II implementation)

Definition:

```
class Biquad{

public:

    Biquad(double a0, double a1, double a2, double b0, double b1, double b2) {
        this->a0 = a0;
        this->a1 = a1;
        this->a2 = a2;
        this->b0 = b0;
        this->b1 = b1;
        this->b2 = b2;
        z1 = z2 = 0.0;
    }

    double filter(double in) {
        double out = z1 + b0 * in;
        z1 = z2 + b1 * in - a1 * out;
        z2 = b2 * in - a2 * out;
        return out;
    }

private:
    double a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;
    double z1, z2;
};
```

Initialization:

```
Biquad *a1Filter = new Biquad(1.0000000, -0.1405361, 0.0049376, 0.2557411, -0.5114387, 0.2556976);
Biquad *a2Filter = new Biquad(1.0000000, -1.8849012, 0.8864215, 1.0000000, -2.0001702, 1.0001702);
Biquad *a3Filter = new Biquad(1.0000000, -1.9941389, 0.9941475, 1.0000000, 2.0000000, 1.0000000);
```

Invocation:

```
double outputValue = a3Filter->filter(a2Filter->filter(a1Filter->filter(inputValue)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results you quote it would seem that you are actually using Octave's [`bilinear`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/bilinear.html) (known to have some [incompatibilities with Matlab](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?38297)) for which the third argument is the sampling period (instead of the sampling frequency for [Matlab's `bilinear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html)).

To work around this problem, you can get the sampling period as `1/Fs` and correspondingly compute your coefficients with:

```
[B,A] = bilinear(NUMs,DENs,1/Fs);
```

You should then be able to confirm the filter response with:

```
fmin = 10;    % Hz
fmax = 20000; % Hz
omega = logspace(log10(2*pi*fmin), log10(2*pi*fmax));
Ha = freqs(NUMs,DENs,omega);
hold off; semilogx(omega/(2*pi), 20*log10(abs(Ha)), 'b');

N = ceil(Fs/fmin);
[Hd,W] = freqz(B,A,N);
hold on; semilogx(W*Fs/(2*pi), 20*log10(abs(Hd)), 'r');
```

This should give you the graph below (blue curve being the reference, and the red one obtained from your coefficients):

[image]

Comment: Note that the bilinear transform causes the red to roll-off more quickly than the blue, introducing error in the measurement. A simple fix is to [upsample the data first](https://www.vocal.com/echo-cancellation/a-and-c-weighting-via-bilinear-transform/).  Other approaches here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36077/29